error staging test on sepolia testnet(1) Uncaught error outside test suite)
I'm trying to deploy a smart contract on the sepolia testnet ,so the contract is deployed successfully as seen on the etherscan ,but when im trying to test the contract with staging test by running command hh test --network sepolia
it gives 1) Uncaught error outside test suite 
The code is
const { expect, assert } = require("chai")

const { network, getNamedAccounts, deployments, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { networkConfig, developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")
const { log } = require("console")

developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Lottery unit test", async () => {
          let lottery, getEntranceFee
          beforeEach(" test", async () => {
              const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

              lottery = await ethers.getContract("Lottery", deployer)
              getEntranceFee = await lottery.getEntranceFee()
          })
          describe("fulfillRandomWords", async () => {
              it("works with live Chainlink Keepers and Chainlink VRF, we get a random winner", async () => {
                  console.log("Setting up test...")
                  const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
                  const startTime = await lottery.getLastTimeStamp()
                  let startingBalance
                  console.log("Setting up Listener...")
                  await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                      lottery.once("winnerPicked", async () => {
                          console.log("WinnerPicked event fired!")
                          try {
                              const lotteryState = await lottery.getLotteryState()
                              const recentWinner = await lottery.getRecentWinner()
                              const endTime = await lottery.getLastTimeStamp()
                              const endingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance()
                              const entranceFee = await lottery.getEntranceFee()
                              await expect(lottery.getPlayers(0)).to.be.reverted
                              assert.equal(lotteryState, 0)
                              assert.equal(endTime > startTime)
                              assert.equal(recentWinner, accounts[0].address)
                              assert.equal(
                                  endingBalance.toString(),
                                  startingBalance.add(entranceFee).toString()
                              )
                              resolve()
                          } catch (e) {
                              console.log(e)
                              reject(e)
                          }
                      })
                      console.log("Entering Raffle...")
                      const tx = await lottery.participateLottery({
                          value: lottery.getEntranceFee(),
                      })
                      await tx.wait(1)
                      console.log("now time to wait")
                      startingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance()
                  })
              })
          })
      })


The hardhat.config.js file is
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("hardhat-deploy")
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
require("hardhat-contract-sizer")
require("dotenv").config()
const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL =
    process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL 
const PRIVATE_KEY =
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY 
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || ""
const COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY = process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY || ""

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            chainId: 31337,
            blockConfirmations: 1,
            // forking: {
            //     url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            // },
        },
        sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 11155111,
            gasPrice: 300000000,
            blockConfirmations: 6,
        },
    },
    solidity: "0.8.7",
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0,
        },
        player: {
            default: 1,
        },
    },
    gasReporter: {
        enabled: process.env.REPORT_GAS,
        outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
        noColors: true,
        currency: "USD",
        // coinmarketcap: COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
        token: "ETH",
        gasPriceApi: "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_gasPrice",
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: {
            sepolia: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
        },
        customChains: [],
    },
    mocha: {
        timeout: 500000,
    },
}

Also the code is passing on the local hardhat testnet successfully
Can anyone tell me where my code is going wrong and what should I do to correct it .

When testing on live networks like Ethereum mainnet or testnet, forking is recommended, as forking allows you to simulate the state of the live mainnet or testnet locally, enabling you to interact with your deployed contracts and test complex interactions without affecting the live network.
To test against a testnet or mainnet fork using Hardhat, you need to configure your hardhat.config.js file to include the forking configuration.
This involves specifying the RPC URL of the testnet/mainnet you want to fork from. You can also optionally pin the fork to a specific block number to ensure consistency across test runs.
Here's how you can set up your hardhat.config.js for forking:
module.exports = {
 solidity: "0.8.24",
 networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: "https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/YOUR_ALCHEMY_API_KEY",
        // blockNumber: 5000000 // Optional: Pin the fork to a specific block number
      }
    }
 }
}

With this config, you don't need to pass --network flag anymore, you can simply run:
npx hardhat test

Example:
A minimal example to run the test using forking can be found in this repo, where the price feed version on the Sepolia testnet is checked and matched as 4.

I have not learnt about forking yet and after using it I get an error specifying
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":75,"error":{"code":429,"message":"Your app has exceeded its compute units per second capacity. If you have retries enabled, you can safely ignore this message. If not, check out https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/throughput"}}
.Is there any other way for the problem as I cant figure out anything else and also I want know about the error ,like why I am getting this.

Seems like you've exhausted the number of free API calls to Alchemy. Try using some public RPC url like https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com. The list of public RPC urls is available on Chainlist.

okay ,so I can use my alchemy key correctly ,but when I run hh test, it still runs the test that was meant for the local development ,not the test that was for the sepolia testnet. can you explain why this happens and how to correct it . and also if I run hh deploy , it says local network detected .

Can you share your hardhat.config.js?

I have updated the question with hardhat.config.js file ,please look into it

@DivyanshuMadhav, I've added a repository link in my answer showcasing the minimal example of testing using sepolia fork. Please check.

I have seen the repo, But that doesn't address my concern ,my concern is that if I add  the following line to the test file "hardhat.includes(network.name) ? describe.skip : "the remaining test".The test will not run on the forked network,but if I deploy it on the sepolia testnet,it will run as intended.So the original problem still persists that the forked network doesn't run the test that are intended for  the testnet and not the local deployment. So how to resolve the issue of _1) Uncaught error outside test suite _ when I am deploying  the staging test on the testnet.

That’s because the forked network behaves as a local network only, i.e., by forking the live network to your local environment.

Can you share your minimal reproducible code via repo, so that I can try the same on my end?
